# Плавающая кнопка в Android

Tags: android, интерфейс

Добрый день!
Как делают подобные плавающие кнопки (см картинку по [ссылке](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/Telegram_Android_screenshot.png/220px-Telegram_Android_screenshot.png)), синий круг внизу экрана, он может всплывать и исчезать. Он поверх всех элементов.

Кто сталкивался? Спасибо!

Comment: поверх всех элементов - z-index

Comment: подобные плавающие кнопки - position: fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 0):

Свойства кнопки:

```
position:fixed;
-webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
-moz-transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
-o-transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
transition: top 1s ease-out 0.5s;
bottom:15px;
right:15px;
opacity:1;
```

И на JS, ссылаясь на особенности  Android Material, про скролле изменять opacity и bottom в зависимости от направления скролла